# EF how to invert an object hierarchy

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have a list of Users in a family `var foo = someUser.MyFamily();`
Each User has a list of Classes `public virtual List<Class> Classes {get; set;}`
Each Class has a list of Dates `public virtual List<Date> Dates {get; set;}`

To display what's on this week for the family, I'd like to create a table

```
    date    class    people...
            class    people...
    date+   class    people
```

So what I really want is to invert this arrangement and have
A list of relevant Dates,
Each Date having a list of Classes,
Each Class having a list of Users (but only users in the family)

I'm stuck figuring out how to say it. I keep thinking it should go something like this

```
var foo = Users x Classes x Dates as in a join
.GroupBy(x => x.Date)
.Select(x => new { something })    
.GroupBy(x => x.Class)
.Select(x => new { something })    
etc...
```

and end up being able to say

```
foreach (var d in foo)
{
    use d.Date
    foreach (var c in d.Classes)
    {
        use c.Class.ClassTime, c.Class.ClassName
        foreach (var u in c.Users)
        {
            use u.FirstName
```

Thanks for insight.

Comment: Eric you can have that type of 'thinking' if you have many-to-many (except for users-family) - which is approximated with one-to-many (model). And if you have m-2-m then easiest is to rework your entity model - to direct relations in the opposite direction. Then you can have a 'native' linq query w/o any effort at all. Providing you can change the model

Comment: @NSGaga I see your point, and in fact it's possible with the current model. ClassTime -> Class -> UsersInClass works but it gives me a huge result set of all meetings of all classes containing all users. Somehow I would have to join that against the list of family members. I can't think how to do that. Anyway, it seems like it would be faster to start the join from the family members.

Answer (score 1):

**I GOT IT !!!!!**

Thanks to this article I learned how to use SelectMany to flatten a hierarchy
 http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2008/10/10/use-linqs-selectmany-method-to-flatten-collections/;

Once I had it flattened it was straightforward to use `GroupBy()` to rebuild the object hierarchy from Dates -> Meetings -> Users such that
Each Date has a list of Meetings
Each Meeting has a list of Users

```
var meetingDates = Model.User.MyFamily(true)
    .SelectMany(x => x.ClassesIamIn)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Class.ClassMeetings, (c, d) => new { Date = d.Date, Meeting = d, c.User })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Date)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Date = x.Key,
        Meetings = x.Select(y => new { Meeting = y.Meeting, User = y.User })
            .GroupBy(a => a.Meeting)
            .Select(a => new
            {
                Meeting = a.Key,
                Users = a.Select(b => b.User)
                    .OrderBy(d => d.FirstName)
            })
            .OrderBy(c => c.Meeting.TimeStart.TimeOfDay)
    });
```

Wow this has been a struggle; wow what a relief. The above article was the key. I had known how to use SelectMany() to drill inside lists. The thing I didn't know was the goofy lambda syntax for creating a thing that includes the parent object in it `(parent, child) => new { parent child mix }`